# Conversion C# to VB.net Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

Need vb.net conversion of the below:
orginal question at [LINQ To SQL "Group By"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984321/linq-to-sql-group-by)

```
from S in SERVER
join H in SERVERHDD on S.Server_ID equals H.Server_ID
join FILTER in 
(from s in SERVERHDD group s 
        by new {s.Server_ID, s.Letter} 
        into groupedServerHDD select new 
                {
                        SERVERHDD_ID = groupedServer.Sum(gS=>gS.ServerHDD_ID)
                }
)
 on H.ServerHDD_ID equals FILTER.SERVERHDD_ID 
 orderby S.Hostname, H.Letter
 select S
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may want to try refactormycode.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ and untested.

```
Dim x = From S In SERVER _
    Join H In SERVERHDD On S.Server_ID = H.Server_ID _
    Join FILTER In (From s In SERVERHDD _
        Group s By New ()IntogroupedServerHDD _
        Select New ()) On H.ServerHDD_ID = FILTER.SERVERHDD_ID _
    Order By S.Hostname, H.Letter _
    Select S
```

Comment: Thank Mathew for guidance: Got this solved as :
Dim query = From S In db.SERVERs _
            Join H In db.SERVERHDDs On S.Server_ID = H.Server_ID _
            Join FILTER In (From s In db.SERVERHDDs _
            Group s By s.Server_ID, s.Letter _
            Into ServerHDD_Ids = Sum(s.ServerHDD_ID) Order By ServerHDD_Ids Ascending) _
            On H.ServerHDD_ID = FILTER.SERVERHDD_ID _
            Order By S.Hostname, H.Letter _
            Select S

Comment: @Nev_Rahd: you might want to edit your post and add the solved solution below your question. It's a lot easier to read with proper code syntax highlight.